# JQuery Sortable initialization after Ajax Update using yii-jui

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, jquery-ui-sortable

I've run into a problem and am looking for the best way to solve it without altering the Yii2 framework.

I have a page which contains elements that can be sorted. I'm using the yii-jui sortable widget and everything works fine after the initial view.

Under certain circumstances I need to update the content with all the elements per ajax. This too is working.

The **problem** is that when I update the content after an ajax call the jquery initialization for the sortable elements and their containers is lost.

When building the initial view the yii-jui extension places the javascript for initializing the Sortable elements in a Javascript block within an on-document-ready function. As I already stated this works fine during the first view. However, when I update the content the initializations are lost and somehow I need to run the javascript initialization again. I cannot do this because the on-document-ready function is not triggered.

A possible solution would be to place all the JS initialization for the sortable elements into a separate function and call this explicitly after the first view and also after an ajax update. The difficulty is that I see no way to do this with the yii-jui widget as it places all the initialization (events and options) as singular calls in the on-document-ready function.

**I've considered the following**:

- Add an option to yii-jui widget to place the initialization steps
  into a JS function
- Use a view event hook to manipulate the JS
  bundle/asset settings prior to building the HTML, so that I can
  create the function I need
- Do not use the native options in the
  yii-jui widget but write a separate initialization script of my own.

Any ideas at how I could best proceed?

Thanks for any input

Andy Potter

Answer (score 1):

As you already have jquery in your view, you need to prevent yii2 from loading it again with the ajax request (you could consider some other files too, like yii.js):

```
$view->on(View::EVENT_END_PAGE, function($event){ 

    $positions = $event->sender->jsFiles;
    foreach($positions as $position => $js){
        $new = array_filter($js, 
        function($item){
            return !preg_match('/jquery(\.min)?\.js|yii(\.min)?\.js/i', $item);
        });
        $event->sender->jsFiles[$position] = $new;
    }

});
```

You can filter as many js files as you need by adding them to the `preg_match` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

By 'hooking' into the View **EVENT_END_PAGE** event I was able to alter the generated Javascript code and place it into a function.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = 'main-full';
    Yii::$app->getUser()->setReturnUrl(Yii::$app->request->getUrl());

    $this->getView()->on(View::EVENT_END_PAGE, [$this, 'jsAsFunction']);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'board' => $this->currentBoard,
        'columnHtml' => $this->getColumnHtml(),
    ]);
}

public function jsAsFunction($event)
{
    $event->sender->js[View::POS_HEAD] = ['var initializeBoard;'];
    $event->sender->js[View::POS_HEAD] = ['var longPollingTimeout = ' . self::LONG_POLLING_TIMEOUT . ';'];
    $event->sender->js[View::POS_READY] = array_merge(
        ['initializeBoard = function() {'],
        $event->sender->js[View::POS_READY],
        ['}'],
        ['initializeBoard();']
    );

    return true;
}
```

When the View generates the Inline Javascript all the array elements are imploded together. So I just surrounded the code inside a function declaration. After that it is available at a later point.

**Important**

- The function must be called explicitly after it has been declared
- In order for the function to be available outside of the scope of
  jQuery(document).ready it must be assigned to a variable that has
  been declared with global scope. Thus the first two assignments that
  are generated into the `<HEAD>` area.